# JMeter - Execute Multiple Scripts in Non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have 6 scripts to be executed one after the other (Non-GUI mode).

Using Batch Files to achieve the same. Kindly find below the approach taken:

File with Parameters

[image]

File with Execution commands

[image]

Is there a better approach to implement this?

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a "better" approach, there are "alternative" approaches i.e.

1. You can create one "umbrella" .jmx script and reference all your 6 scripts using [Include Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)
2. You can use [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter tests, example [Taurus YAML config file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/):

   ```
   execution:
   - scenario: test1
   - scenario: test2
   # etc.

   scenarios:
     test1:
       script: test1.jmx
     test2: 
       script: test2.jmx
   #etc   

   modules:
     local:
       sequential: true
   ```